# What is IsNull in HQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, isnull

How to write an HQL query like this SQL Query?

```
SELECT IsNull(name, '') FROM users
```

When I search for HQL IsNull, All results are for IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the **[Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html)** you can see that they provide many useful expressions for such statements, you can check the [**CASE expressions** section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3289) where it says that you can use **[`coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)** expression instead of `ISNull()`.

So your query will be:

```
SELECT coalesce(name, '') FROM users
```

You can check their [**Simple case expression example**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3298) for further details.